# Python code snippet throw 500 in CKAN

Tags: python, pylons, mako, ckan, opendata

I'm using CKAN to develop an open data portal. It uses Python as the language and Pylons as the framework

I use the below code snippets the get the API link as mentioned in the question. Please refer [this questio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943637/how-to-enable-api-button-for-ckan-data-set)n for more info. But it does not work for me.

## Method 1

```
<b>API: </b><a href="${h.url_for(controller='api', register='package', action='show', id=c.pkg.name, ver='2')}">
${h.url_for(controller='api', register='package', action='show', id=c.pkg.name, ver='2')}
</a>
```

## Method 2

```
<b>API: </b><a href="{% h.url_for(controller='api', register='package', action='show', id=c.pkg.name, ver='2') %}">
{% h.url_for(controller='api', register='package', action='show', id=c.pkg.name, ver='2') %}
</a>
```

Both above throw 500 error as shown below in the images.

[image]

**How could I fix this error?**

Comment: That does not look like the [Django template language](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/templates/#templates), especially you can't just call functions with arguments in the Django template language

Comment: What's correct way to do it? Please help me if possible. I'm new to Python. I'm more of a PHP guy.

Comment: If you look at the [requirements.txt](https://github.com/datagovuk/ckan/blob/master/requirements.txt) for ckan, it doesn't mention Django at all. It uses the Pylons framework with the Mako template language

Comment: Thanks for the correction. Can you please tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<a class="btn btn-primary resource-url-analytics resource-type-{{ res.resource_type }}" href="{{h.url_for(controller='api', register='package', action='show', id=c.pkg.name, ver=2)}}">
    <i class="icon-eye-open"></i> {{ _('API') }}
</a>
```

Above code works fine for me.